# как добавлять к переменной значение, но после события начать отнимать его?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, классы, pygame

в этом коде по умолчанию прибавляется 5, но после касания к краю окна должно отниматься, таким образом должен создастся эффект отскока, но я не знаю как это реализовать

```
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)

    def update(self):
        while True:
            self.rect.x += 5
            if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.speed_x = 5


def update(self):
    while True:
        self.rect.x += self.speed_x
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH: 
              self.speed_x = -5
```

Comment: я пробывал с While, окно зависает, потомучто само окно тоже цикл и пока не сломать цикл в update, цикл обновления окна не будет работать. если надо, могу скинуть полный код

Comment: Тут ответ на вопрос, который вы задали. Если есть какие-то другие проблемы, то их нужно описать в подробностях, вероятно в отдельном вопросе(-ах), а не в комментариях.

Comment: да, спасибо, я уже понял свою ошибку. извините, сам забыл убрать цикл после тестов, и подумал что это написали вы, извините